# What is the little banner than drops behind the action bar called?

Tags: android

I want to use it in my app but I can't find any resources about it because I don't know that it's called. It's kind of like a toast notification in that it transiently notifies the user of things but it just comes down behind the action bar and then goes to hide again. Here's an example screenshot (I'm referring to the red banner that says Network Error):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One term for them is "crouton". There's a [library](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton), too.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that there'd be an official API for them in Android (since I've seen them around quite a bit) but evidently not. Checking out the library now! EDIT: Wow, turns out that after installing the library it's as easy as displaying a toast notification.

Answer (score 2):

I think the library that used in your photo is [AppMessage](https://github.com/johnkil/Android-AppMsg)